# How to display an array of TextViews in android dynamically?

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

I want to display 26 textviews. How to display an array of TextViews in android dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the bellow code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        // or get your TextView from array
        char c=(char)(65+i);
        tv.setText(" "+c);
        ll.addView(tv);
    }
    setContentView(ll);
 }
```

but this type of design is not good,instead try to use **ListView** with **CustomAdapters**.

Answer (score 2):

Create an xml layout which consist of a scrollview containing a linearlayout with orientation vertical.

In the activity, get the linear layout by using findViewById function.

Run a for loop to create a textview with relevant text and continue calling

addView method on this LinearLayout.